# StructureMap/Autofac: how to create objects based on web.config settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap, autofac

I've got a `ConfigurationReader` class that I'm trying to wire up using StructureMap or AutoFac (I haven't settled on which container I'm using).

```
public class ConfigurationReader {
  private string _filePath;
  public ConfigurationReader(string filePath){
     this._filePath = filePath;
  }
   public IList<Baz> ListStuff(){
    //do something with _filePath;
   }

}
```

There will be 1..n to instances of this class based on how the app is configured (web.config  will contain a delimited list of files).  I'm looking for an extension point in either IoC container that would allow me to leverage them to create instances of `ConfigurationReader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in AutoFac you can just register each one in the Container (during `Application_Start` for example).

Whenever you need to read all configurations you can add a dependency to `IEnumerable<ConfigurationReader>` (or `IConfigurationReader` if you decide to extract an interface) and it will provide you with all of them.

Something like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
foreach(var file in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[yourKey].Split(',')) 
{
    var fileName = file;
    builder.Register(c => new ConfigurationReader(fileName));
}
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder.Build()));
```

If you extract interfaces, then you may want to register by adding the `.AsImplementedInterfaces()` or `.As<IConfigurationReader>()` at end as well.

Comment: I *think* there's a bug in this related to a lambda accessing the variable of your foreach loop.

Comment: You are correct, should prob change that for a local reference. I'll change it.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Muchas Gracias senor.

Comment: Fue un placer, señor Mitch :P